# Import MySQL dump into a specific tablespace

Tags: mysql, database, import

Windows 7 64-bit
MySQL 5.7

All,

I have a server with two drives: C: & E:.
I want to have all my database objects (tables, indexes, etc...) created/stored on the E drive as it is a larger disk.
I have a dump file from a previous MySQL instance that I want to import into a tablespace (ts1) located on E.  (I actually have two versions of the dump file - one with just the create tables/procedures, and another with the data included.)
Is there a way to import the dump file with data so that all objects and data end up in ts1 on E:?

I've tried changing the datadir in my my.ini(cfg) file, but when I attempt to restart the instance/service it fails (Windows tells me the service attempted to start then stopped.)

Can someone tell me the recommended way to import a dump file into a specific tablespace?  This is my own personal development server, so can afford downtime, can blow away the instance or any other radical solution that may be proposed.

I am a former senior Oracle DBA (so I maybe thinking of tablespaces incorrectly) but a "1 month old" when it comes to MySQL (so please don't rule out basic/simple advice).

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't yet support defining a default tablespace for all tables in a schema. You can only declare a tablespace explicitly per table.

So I suggest you will need two dump files: one with only data definition language (DDL, i.e. the CREATE TABLE statements) and the second with the data only (the INSERT statements). You can do this with the `mysqldump` program, it has options for `--no-data` and `--no-create-info`. These options produce dump files that contain only DDL, or only INSERT statements respectively. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html for full docs.

Then you can follow this strategy:

1. Run the DDL dump file to create empty tables.
2. [Create a tablespace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/general-tablespaces.html) and define it with a datafile on your E: drive.
3. ALTER TABLE for each of your tables and make them use the new general tablespace on E:.
4. Run your data dump file to import the data.

Maybe you no longer have the ability to make dump files from your previous MySQL installation. You just have the current dump file. Then you might have to figure out how to separate the CREATE TABLE statements from the data file using a text editor that won't die if you give it a large file, or else a filtering text tool like `sed`.

Comment: This worked.  As you guessed, I do not have the ability to make dump files.  I had created separate dumps already. Also, my file was 36GB in size.  I used UltraEdit to comment out the drop table statements and replace the Create table statements with create table if not exist statements.  UltraEdit allows you to search and replace in files without opening them in the editor.  THANK YOU FOR THIS.